# Find Weights to a Linear Vector Combination

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-programming, orthonormal

I have a problem I am stuck at.

Suppose object $a$ in a vector space is represented by a subspace, i.e., a set of orthonormal vectors $(u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_n)$. I want to represent $a$ as a single vector. How should I be finding the weights,

$a = \alpha_1 u_1 + \alpha_2 u_2 + \ldots + \alpha_n u_n$

How to find these alpha? Any standard method?

I think if I can find a vector for $a$ close enough to compare then there must be a method that tries to minimize the loss between $a$ and its reconstruction in terms of linear combination.

Comment: Put $u_1,u_2,..,u_n$ as columns in the matrix $A$. Then solve $Ax=a$ using elimination.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla then, Ax with the solved x is the required vector representation for "a", right? I will need to find the least squares solution for this probably? THx.

Comment: That's the hard way. Since the basis is orthonormal, $u_i$ is just the inner product of $a$ and $\alpha_i$.

Comment: Yes, Supposing the matrix is square, then that $A^T=A^{-1}$ for such (orthogonal) matrix. So $x=A^{-1}a=A^Ta$ as noted is an easier way of getting to the answer @Rafael